# Argument of length zero in R after if function

Tags: r

I am getting an argument of length zero after running the code below. I have looked at other users with this issue, however I am unable to figure out the error.

```
gi <- pm%*%t(pm); #creates a 5k by 5k matrix by multiplying matrix by its transpose
dim(gi); # checks dimensions of matrix
ngen <- dim(pm)[1];
select <- matrix(F,ncol=ngen,nrow=ngen);
for(i in 1:(ngen-1)){
    for(ii in (i+1):ngen){
        if(gi[i,ii] < llim){
            next;
        }
        hit1 <- p.sum[i];
        hit2 <- p.sum[ii];
        if(gi[i,ii] >= qmat[hit1,hit2]){
            select[i,ii] <- TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

This code returns the error:

```
Error in if (gi[i, ii] >= qmat[hit1, hit2]) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

I have a feeling that the problem is the `gi` variable as `hit1` and `hit2` return values, any ideas how I could fix it? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Qmat is the following:  qmat
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    2
'

Comment: Does `p.sum` contain indexes?  In general, we can not test your code because we don't have `pm`, `llim`, `p.sum`, or `qmat`.

Comment: `table(pm)
pm
   0    1 
9909   91 `, `llim <- 0`, `p.sum <- apply(pm,1,sum) `

Comment: `dim(pm)` gives [1] 5000    2

Comment: @user1286656 You should really add those details to the question so people don't have to go searching through the comments in an attempt to help you out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely reason for the failure is that `hit1` or `hit2` returns `0`.

```
m <- matrix(1:12,4)
m[0,3] # integer(0)
if (m[0,3] > 0) 'foo!'
#Error in if (m[0, 3] > 0) "foo!" : argument is of length zero
```

...And you can use `tcrossprod(pm)` instead of `pm%*%t(pm)` - it's faster and (in my opinion) clearer.

Comment: `hit1` returns, 8136159 0   and `hit2` returns 7948894 0

Comment: Thanks Tommy, after reviewing the code the error indeed was that hit1 and hit2 returned zero.

Comment: @user1286656 Bingo! ;-) Then you might want to accept it as the answer... Also see my comment on `tcrossprod` above.